# Cloud Functions for firebase returning response 500

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is the function I'm invoking

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const router = new express.Router();

 router.use(cors);  
 router.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').status(200)
            .send('Hello, Functions');
    });

exports.date = functions.https.onRequest(router);
```

But I'm getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://us-central1-idntt-baed5.cloudfunctions.net/date. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://idntt-baed5.firebaseapp.com' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Did you slove that error?

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for what you are trying to do would be:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Start writing Firebase Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello, Functions");
})
```

now you should go to like this https://us-central1-idntt-baed5.cloudfunctions.net/date.

and you not allow use Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. When I hit the url directly it works, but when I use an XMLHttpRequest from a static page I get this error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us-central1-idntt-baed5.cloudfunctions.net/date. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://idntt-baed5.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for what you are trying to do would be:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello, Functions");
})
```

It may produce a error like this,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us-central1-idntt-baed5.cloudfunctions.net/date. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://idntt-baed5.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Please use this header in *xhr* request

```
req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Try to run in mozilla firefox, Google chrome does not support this due to security issues

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting the function through a site/page hosted in firebase you (firebase hosting) should add a rewrite rule. It is explained in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#directing_hosting_requests_to_your_function